# What is the difference between javascript property and javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

While assigning values in javascript I came across this

```
var obj = {
  resultCodeId: data[i].resultCodes[j].resultCodeId
};
var resultCodeId= data[i].resultCodes[j].resultCodeId;
```

How do ':' and '=' fundamentally differ in javascript ?Can variable also have properties or just objects in javascript have properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=` is for object property or global/local variable assignment.
`:` is only for property assignment at object definition.

Also:
You can `delete` a property.
You cannot `delete` a variable.

```
var obj = {
  p1: 'im p1',
  p2: 2
};
obj.p1 = 'im updated p1'; // assign a new value to object property
var v = 'just a var'; // is global outside a function and local inside a function

delete obj.p1; // is ok
delete v; // is not ok
```

Comment: So basic difference just lies between deletion?? No other differences?

Comment: @rahulb - well that's a subtle difference between a variable and an object property - the main answer I think is the difference between object property assignment. colon is only used in object definition (not variable assignment)

Comment: So colon cannot be used to reassign values to properties? Is it always used while first assigning values to properties? Then how we will override the properties?

Comment: Correct. When you say override, if you mean reassign a value, then see my example - you use equals.

Answer (score 3):

There's a big difference if you use member functions. Local variables are immediately visible, but properties aren't. They require `this`. But -- this is the big difference -- sometimes member functions can't see their own properties at all. Some standard code, with a basic constructor:

```
function Cat() { // constructor with a var and property
  var a="local a"; // variable
  this.b="local b"; // property

  this.showBad = function() { return a+", "+b; } // local a, but searches for b in global
  this.showGood = function() { return a+", "+this.b; } // local a and b (but has a bug, explained below)
}

var c1=new Cat(); // using the constructor
var a="GLOBAL A", b="GLOBAL B"; // if we can't see c1's locals, we get these

console.log(c1.showBad()); // local a, GLOBAL B // oops on B
console.log(c1.showGood()); // local a, local b // works fine, using "this"
```

So far, no big deal. Properties need `this`, while variables don't (they actually can't have it). Minor stuff. But `this` won't always work. In a javascript member function `this` can be anything. If you're accustomed to an OOP language, that seems wrong. Here we call `c1.showGood` with `this` set to the global scope:

```
var sGood=c1.showGood; // sGood is the function "c1.showGood"
console.log(sGood()); // local a, GLOBAL B // Argg. this.b didn't work!
```

That seems fake, but things like that can happen. Because of those two things (vars always work, and we need a reliable way to always see our properties), a standard trick is to lock-down your `this` in a variable during construction. It shows the var/property difference nicely:

```
function Cat() { // constructor with a var and property
  var self = this; // self is our permanent, always visible link to this Cat
  this.a="local a";
  this.b="local b";

  this.showGood = function() { return self.a+", "+self.b; }
}
```

`self` is a variable, so our `showGood` can always find ours. Meanwhile `a` and `b` can only be found using a link, which `self` accomplishes.

Answer (score 2):

The ':' is used in an object way to assign a key to a value as a key/value pair. The '=' is an assignment operator. It assigns a variable to a value.

Yes a variable can have properties because a variable can be assigned an object.

Answer (score 2):

A property is usually associated with a javascript object.

```
var obj = {
  name: 'test', --> property
  getName: function(){ --> property
    return this.name
  }
};
```

In contrary variables are used inside functions and even outside of them.

```
var global = "string"; --> variable
function test(){
  var local = "string"; --> variable
}
```

But the underlying idea of both the property and a variable remains the same, which is to either store or point to an object in memory.

- ':' is used whenever you want to associate a attribute to an object.
- '=' is used whenever you want to store the actual data or a reference in memory

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your example for explanation,

- **var obj = {   resultCodeId: data[i].resultCodes[j].resultCodeId };**
  *this means resultCodeId is a memeber of "obj" object. You can access it like **obj.resultCodeId**.*
- **var resultCodeId= data[i].resultCodes[j].resultCodeId;**
  *This is a global variable and all global variables are properties of the window object.so you can access it like **window.resultCodeId**.*

**In Addition:**

**var resultCodeId= data[i].resultCodes[j].resultCodeId;** 
*this statement within a object/function will be treated as local varible and can be accessed within that object/function only.*

Answer (score 0):

`:` is related to the creation of an obj (and its properties)

```
let obj = {prop1: true, prop2: false};
```

`=` is related to some definition (of a variable, function, obj, property or something else) during the execution

```
obj.prop1 = false;
obj.prop2 = true;
let foo;
foo = function(){}
let variable;
variable = true;
```

only objs have properties (but almost everything in JS is an obj; a function is an obj; we have the global/window obj; and so on)